# HTC Evo 3D not recognized in Eclipse/AndroidStudio

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, device

I have a GREAT trouble connecting to my Android phone for debugging on Windows 8. Now a couple of things that I have already tried:

- I **have** Google USB drivers installed
- I **did** check the adb, it shows no devices whatsoever
- I **tried** showing all hidden devices in Device Manager and uninstalling them all
- I **tried** to uninstall the device (which is seen as 'other devices' and with a yellow questio mark), then plug out, plug in - and it's still the same
- I **tried** to use the useless Windows driver update tool, but of course it doesn't find any suitable driver
- HTC Sync **doesn't** see the device, even after update
- Also **tried to manually copy** the device address and insert into adb_usb.ini and android_winusb.inf so that adb has this model in its list

I have no clue what else to do. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you still need a usb-driver for it. Perhaps this might help: http://singledrivers.blogspot.com.es/2014/01/download-htc-evo-3d-usb-driver-for.html

Comment: This is exactly what I stumbled upon moments ago. Of course you're right!

Comment: I will move the suggestion to an answer then :)

Comment: People who mindlessly download and run executables of unknown origin deserve every bit of trouble they eventually get in. Here is how you make a truly universal android adb driver from the official Google USB Driver pack http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need a usb-driver for it. This might help:
http://singledrivers.blogspot.com.es/2014/01/download-htc-evo-3d-usb-driver-for.html

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable [USB Debugging](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#developer-device-options) on your device?